# Reading every file format as 0's and 1's

Tags: compression

I am making a file compressor using Huffman Coding. I want to read the file in binary (1's and 0's) , whatever be the format of the file. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: By the way, efficient Huffman decoding does not need to read the file bit by bit, so you can avoid this problem entirely by implementing a more mature decoding algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to read the file in binary mode.  (Under some operating systems, like MS Windows, reading in text mode will corrupt any bytes that happen to look like newlines.)

Second, you will need to decide what order to read the bits in each byte:  least significant bit (LSB) first, or most significant bit (MSB) first.  It doesn't matter which order you choose, as long as you're consistent (and, of course, you must write the bits in the same order as you wish to read them!)

Finally, you will need to use bitwise operators to access the individual bits.  An example (in the form of a partial C++ class):

```
class bit_buffer {
public:
    bit_buffer(std::istream *input): m_input(input) {}

    bool get_bit() {
        if (m_bit_idx < 0) {
            m_input->get(m_char);
            m_bit_idx = 7;
        }
        bool retval = (m_char >> m_bit_idx) & 0x01;
        -- m_bit_idx;
        return retval;
    }
private:
    std::istream *m_input;
    unsigned char m_char;
    int m_bit_idx = -1;
}
```

Note that the above code reads the bits most-significant-bit (MSB) first.

Comment: Does it work for any type of file? Can you elaborate it please? I am just begginer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If you're designing your own file format (which your question suggests you are), you get to decide how to read and write the file.  If you're using an existing file format, you need to read the specification to figure out how to read and write the file.